# Configure rules for Atom's linter-markdown package on a per project basis?

Tags: markdown, atom-editor, remarkjs

I'm using the [`linter-markdown`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-markdown) package in Atom for writing tidy Markdown.

Generally I prefer having the package option `Strict markdown style by default` active. It adds the rule preset `remark-preset-lint-markdown-style-guide` based on Ciro Santilli's [Markdown Style Guide](http://www.cirosantilli.com/markdown-style-guide/) to the checks.

But sometimes, for example when working with [Slate](https://github.com/lord/slate), external factors force me to break one or two of the strict Markdown Style Guide rules.

For those cases I would like to be able to manually deactivate those rules, **but only for the particular project**.

`linter-markdown` uses [`remark-lint`](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint) which supports a [`.remarkrc` configuration file](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configuring-remark-lint).

If I put a `.remarkrc` file with the following content in the same directory as the Markdown file in question, it definitely does get picked up. But the linter then fails with a fatal error, also shown below.

**`.remarkrc`:**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "remark-preset-lint-markdown-style-guide",
    ["no-multiple-toplevel-headings", false]
  ]
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Could not find module `remark-preset-lint-markdown-style-guide`...
```

Does anyone know of a good way to customize the linter rules for the `linter-markdown` Atom package **on a per project basis**?

Comment: You might have better luck opening an issue on GitHub (at https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint).

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem, placing the `.remarkrc` file in my home directory. It seems like either:

- That snippet of code, from the [remarkjs/remark-lint](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint#configuring-remark-lint) page on GitHub, so you would think that it is right, doesn't include the configuration needed to find the base file (`remark-preset-lint-recommended`), or
- The base file has been removed or renamed.

In either case removing the reference to the base file so that the snippet reads:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["remark-lint-list-item-indent", false]
  ]
}
```

got around my immediate problem - I no longer have every list item flagged. I'm guessing that `linter-markdown` has a set of defaults that it is pulling from somewhere -- presumably based on the Settings checkboxes.

**EDIT:** after a bit more poking around I found a reference on the [NPM page for installing the base file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-preset-lint-recommended). Following those instructions also makes the error go away, but not in a very tidy way -- the package is installed in the current directory. I, somewhat, resolved this by installing in my home directory, but that's a kludge. It does get found there. Clearly there is more to understand here as it seems that `linter-markdown` uses a different method for setting defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration in the root of my markdown project, and it seems to be working right:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "remark-lint"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "commonmark": true,
    "blockquote-indentation": "2",
    "checkbox-character-style": {
      "checked": "x",
      "unchecked": " "
    },
    "code-block-style": "fenced",
    "heading-style": "atx",
    "list-item-spacing": false,
    "no-html": false,
    "no-shortcut-reference-link": true,
    "no-undefined-references": true,
    "ordered-list-marker-value": "ordered",
    "rule-style": "---",
    "unordered-list-marker-style": "-",
    "maximum-line-length": "120"
  }
}
```